# remove words between / Slash

Tags: php, regex

I need to delete words bettwen slashes
I have this string:

```
This a test UP/PL/EX/TU 2013
this a test 2 MG/MF/RS/TB 2007
```

I need this output

```
This a test 2013
this a test 2 2007
```

The string is dinamically, always changes.

CAN BE DONE WHIT REGEX ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: yep it can be done by regex try it!

Comment: If you're using Linux, and specifically KDE, it has a great regex tool that you can use to play around with the regex.  Best way is to play about and see what works and what doesn't.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better expression but given the strings in the question this might be good enough.

```
$string='This a test UP/PL/EX/TU 2013';
$output=preg_replace("/\s[\w\/]+\s/", " ", $string);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$s1 = 'This a test UP/PL/EX/TU 2013';
$s2 = ' this a test 2 MG/MF/RS/TB 2007';

$regex = '|\s*(?:[[:alnum:]]+/)+[[:alnum:]]+\s*|';

echo "$s1 => '", preg_replace($regex, ' ', $s1), "\n";
echo "$s2 => '", preg_replace($regex, ' ', $s2), "\n";
```

Output:

```
This a test UP/PL/EX/TU 2013 => 'This a test 2013
 this a test 2 MG/MF/RS/TB 2007 => ' this a test 2 2007
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~\h*+\w*+\/(?>\w+\/?)++\h*+~', ' ', $string);
```